# maven not reading defined properties

Tags: maven

Don't know why it is not working. I have a couple of defined properties on the POM and I'm running a little script from it which should be able to read these properties, but it's not happening.

This is the POM:

`<properties>
    <propery.one>SOMETHING</propery.one>
    <propery.two>SOMETHING</propery.two>
    <commandline.location>/SOME/PATH/</commandline.location>
    <commandline.executable>commandline-script.sh</commandline.executable>
    ......
</properties>`

`<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>export</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${commandline.executable}</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${commandline.location}</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/scripts/myScript.sh</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>`

I'm calling Maven with this command: mvn deploy (which I suppose. it's the correct one) 
So, once it starts, I can see a lot of exceptions because the script called on this line: "${commandline.executable}" is not reading the properties from the POM.

Help please...

Comment: Can you show the output which implies that something is going wrong?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access to url : ${tac.location}. With hardcoded values it works fine...